# Field "SomeField" doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am sending some details from Postman to mySQL database and it recognizes it but I am getting this error:

```
code: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD',
errno: 1364,
sqlMessage: 'Field \'creditcard\' doesn\'t have a default value',
```

I've set mySQL mode to traditional and removed strict mode, reconnected to the database restarted the server and it's throwing the same error again.

Here is some part of the code:

```
try {
  const createNewUser = 'INSERT INTO users (username, email, phonenumber, password, salt, created_at) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)';
  con.query(createNewUser, [username, email, phonenumber, passHash, salt, createAt], (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(results);
  });
  res.status(201).send({ success: true, message: 'New user was successfully created', data: {username, email, phonenumber, password} });
} catch (error) {
  res.status(500).send({ success: false, message: 'Server error' });
}

await next;
```

}

```
const userCreateModel = `
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    phonenumber VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    creditcard INT(11) NOT NULL,
    salt VARCHAR(255),
    created_at DATE,
    update_at DATE,
    deleted_at DATE,
    lastSignIn DATE,
    PRIMARY key (id)
  )
`;
```

Thank you in advance and I will be very happy if anyone has any clue about what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `creditcard INT(11) NOT NULL` - did you provide data for creditcard?

Comment: @tpschmidt Obviously not as that column does not appear in the column list :)

Comment: then set a default value `creditcard INT(11) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL`, else the `NOT NULL` does not make any sense, right?

Comment: It doesn't work even without the NOT NULL.

Comment: can you paste the new create table code here

Comment: here's the part : creditcard INT(11),

Comment: As create table have create table IF NOT EXISTS it might not have created a new table. try 
show create table users

Comment: It says Table 'users' already exists

Comment: show create table users; -- not just create table users in your mysql editor, not in code

Comment: I wrote that and there's still a NOT NULL next to the credit card even though I changed it in the server, what should I do now?

Comment: Do you have access to connect to DB using mysql editors? Are you authorized to alter table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
creditcard INT(11) NOT NULL,
```

While creating table you mentioned it should not accept null values and while inserting you missed to provide credit card info

So either alter table to accept null values or provide credit card value while inserting

Comment: I removed NOT NULL from the creditcard and it's still not working.

Comment: As create table have create table IF NOT EXISTS it might not have created a new table. try show create table users or alter existing table or drop old table and create a new table

Comment: I got it! Thank you for your help, it meant a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your credit card field is defined as Not Null which is why you are getting this error when you are not giving any value to this field.

Comment: No the error is because a field that is defined as NOT NULL has not been given a value in the insert command

Comment: Yeah sorry I wasn't able to convey what I meant. Edited my answer thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

In your try block, you didn't declare a field for your creditcard